# Best way to prepend an element to an array with and without cloning the original list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to to insert an element into a list.

I've come up with several approaches:

```
// setup
let messages = Array.from({ length: 1e5 }, (_, index) => ({ text: `text for message ${index + 1}` }));
```

The first tests don't clone the original list.

```
const prependMessage1 = () => {
    messages = [{ text:'test message 1' }, ...messages];
};

prependMessage1();

// 531 ops/s ± 4.61%
// 99.5 % slower
```

```
const prependMessage2 = () => {
    messages = [{ text:'test message 2' }].concat(messages);
};

prependMessage2();

// 5.6K ops/s ± 1.49%
// 94.71 % slower
```

```
const prependMessage3 = () => {
    messages.unshift({ text: 'text message 3' })
};

prependMessage3();
// 105K ops/s ± 1.25%
// Fastest ✅
```

```
const prependMessage4 = () => {
    messages.reverse();
    messages.push({ text: 'text message 4' });
    messages.reverse();
};

prependMessage4();

// 4.9K ops/s ± 1.08%
// 95.3 % slower
```

I'm using a state manager in my app that doesn't allow the mutation of the state directly. Each method should return a new object, not mutate the current list of messages. Now what's interesting is that these results change once I start cloning:

```
const prependMessage1 = () => {
    const copy = [...messages];
    messages = [{ text:'test message 1' }, ...copy];
};

prependMessage1();

// 472 ops/s ± 3.19%
// 84.57 % slower
```

```
const prependMessage2 = () => {
    const copy = [...messages];
    messages = [{ text:'test message 2' }].concat(copy);
};

prependMessage2();

// 3.1K ops/s ± 1.09%
// Fastest ✅
```

```
const prependMessage3 = () => {
    const copy = [...messages];
    copy.unshift({ text: 'text message 3' })
    messages = copy;
};

prependMessage3();

// 2.5K ops/s ± 2.28%
// 19.7 % slower
```

```
const prependMessage4 = () => {
    const copy = [...messages];
    copy.reverse();
    copy.push({ text: 'text message 4' });
    copy.reverse();
    messages = copy;
};

prependMessage4();

// 1.2K ops/s ± 1.11%
// 61.14 % slower
```

Based on these tests, is it safe to assume that I should be using `concat`? As the list grows, it seems as though `concat` wins here. Or perhaps there's another most optimal way that I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried `messages = [{ text:'test message 2' }].concat(...messages);`?

Comment: I don't see any functional difference between your two `prependMessage1`, there's no reason to spread into a `copy` first.

Comment: btw, why not use the new `toSpliced` method?

Comment: "*what's interesting is that these results change once I start cloning*" - you're not making sense. Both `messages = [{ text:'test message 1' }, ...messages];` and `messages = [{ text:'test message 2' }].concat(messages);` do create a new array as well, not mutating anything. These are what you should use, they're of course faster than copying everything twice.

Comment: I need to take into account the time that it _would_ take to clone the whole list, as the code snippets above aren't representative of my Effector and Redux logic.

Comment: Why not Array.prototype.slice()

Comment: @NinaScholz `.concat(...messages)` would have to check for every single message object whether it's an array (has `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` to be precise), and it would overflow the stack for a huge number of messages. Definitely prefer `.concat(messages)`.

Comment: @MikeK I don't understand why you say "*would* clone the whole list" - surely you *have* to copy the whole list? In any case, don't trust any benchmarks that are not representative of your actual code.

Comment: `toSpliced` trumps every other test by a __massive__ margin, guess I'll be using that.

Comment: @MikeK you are mistaken because you create a wasted array copy in other tests, check my benchmark

Comment: Bare in mind that `toSpliced` is comparatively very new, so if you care about supporting browsers >1 year old, `cancat` would be a more widely supported choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, seems `concat()` is the fastest. Btw you don't need to copy the messages array in the case of `concat()` and the spread syntax - they create a new copy.

```
` Chrome/120
------------------------------------------------------------
concat              1.00x  |  x1000  164  170  174  174  182
Array::toSpliced    1.09x  |  x1000  179  185  187  192  203
for                 1.41x  |  x1000  231  231  236  239  247
Array::unshift      2.71x  |  x1000  444  450  466  472  484
spread              3.94x  |  x1000  646  653  655  658  660
Array.from         16.71x  |   x100  274  280  281  281  281
------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/120
-----------------------------------------------------------
Array::toSpliced   1.00x  |  x1000  220  230  244  246  271
concat             1.05x  |  x1000  232  234  234  237  238
Array::unshift     1.38x  |  x1000  303  308  310  312  320
for                1.70x  |  x1000  375  396  398  413  425
spread             3.30x  |  x1000  726  727  727  733  735
Array.from         4.73x  |   x100  104  107  107  108  110
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const messages = Array.from({ length: 1e5 }, (_, index) => ({ text: `text for message ${index + 1}` }));

// @benchmark for
const arr = Array(messages.length + 1);
arr[0] = { text:'test message 1' };
for(let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
  arr[i + 1] = messages[i];
}
arr;

// @benchmark concat
[{ text:'test message 1' }].concat(messages);

// @benchmark Array::unshift
{
const arr = messages.slice();
arr.unshift({ text:'test message 1' });
arr;
}

// @benchmark spread
[{ text:'test message 1' }, ...messages];

// @benchmark Array.from
Array.from({length: messages.length + 1}, (_, idx) => idx ? messages[idx - 1] : { text:'test message 1' });

// @benchmark Array::toSpliced

messages.toSpliced(0, 0, { text:'test message 1' });

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```